# ios - Repeating Keys when paginating with Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pagination

I am learning pagination with Firebase. I am using a method in which I store the key of the last added item in the previous page, so the next page can continue from there.

The problem is that when using `ref.queryStarting(at value: lastItemKey)` to keep retrieving items from the last added key, the last item gets repeated twice (since `queryStarting` is inclusive).

And so if I limit to 5 the query I would end up with only 4 new items as 1 would be a duplicate.

The only solution I came up is requesting one more item and remove the repeated one, but I wonder if it´s efficient at all doing it this way. (since we are wasting one item in each query)

If it´s any help, my code looks like this:

```
    // rest of the pages 
    if let lastItemID = lastItemKey {
        itemPageRef = self.itemsRef.queryOrderedByKey().queryStarting(atValue: lastItemID)
            .queryLimited(toFirst: UInt(amount))
    } else {
        // First page of data: we retrieve the first (amount) items
        print("We are in the first page of DATA")
        itemPageRef = self.itemsRef.queryOrderedByKey().queryLimited(toFirst: UInt(amount))
    }

    itemPageRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { [weak self] (snapshot) in
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requesting an overlapping child node between the pages is the only way the Firebase API supports. Since there is no other way to do this, there isn't a more efficient way.

That said, it's typically quite efficient, especially if you use a page size of 25+ child nodes, which is also more reasonable on most use-cases I've seen.